# xpath translate two expressions

Tags: xpath, translation

I can't figure out two expressions in xpath. Can someone help ?

Here they are

1. `substring-after(substring-before(//ul[@id='biblio']/li[3], ']', '['))`
2. `//h2[normalize-space(string())='name']/preceding::h1[1]`

Comment: Please ask only one question at a time. The reason is that you can mark only one answer as accepted, so if two different answers each answers one of your question in a most helpful way, which one would you mark as accepted?

Comment: The expression 1 is not a valid XPath. Compare the number of left and right parentheses.

Comment: Irrespective of that, please clarify what exactly it is you have trouble understanding with. Is a particular function or symbol used in either of the expressions unclear, or is this more about general XPath syntax, or anything else?

Comment: so i would mark first.

Comment: @choroba ;oo now you surprise me... why it is not valid?

Comment: @user3436586: That would hide the fact that (w.l.o.g.) the second answer contains the best solution to your second question. **Possibly misleading** to future visitors with a similar problem. And also, **unfair** toward the author of the second answer. Please don't do that. Create two separate SO questions instead, one for each distinct problem.

Comment: @user3436586: It is not valid because one of the opening brackets never gets closed, and because there is a fullstop after `[3]` where there shouldn't be one.

Comment: these are xpath exressions in some not-created XHTML document. I have to describce the excatly(what they do. etc.) @O.R. Mapper ok, i will remember to do that

Comment: well, i wrongly rewrite them, sorry. just Edited

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first expression:

```
substring-after(substring-before(//ul[@id='biblio']/li[3], ']', '['))
```

First this may find all `ul` elements which are at (self) or a descendant of the context of your XPath. These must have an `id` attribute with the value 'biblio' to me matched, from there it will find the 3rd `li` child element(s) from the matching `ul` element(s).
It will then perform the substring functions on the `text()` of the `li` element(s) after atmomizing them to a string.

So for example if the text of a matched `li` element was `hello [world]`. You would end up with just `world` as the result. As a more complete example, given the XML input:

```
<div>
  <ul id="biblio">
    <li>thing [one]</li>
    <li>thing [two]</li>
    <li>thing [three]</li>
  </ul>
  <ul id="biblio">
    <li>other [a]</li>
    <li>other [b]</li>
    <li>other [c]</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

You would get a sequence of two strings as the result of your XPath expression which would be `three` and `c`. Note that the use of `<div>` in the example input is just a container and could be any element.

Your second expression:

```
//h2[normalize-space(string())='name']/preceding::h1[1]
```

First this may find all the `h2` elements which are at (self) or a descendant of the context of your XPath. These must have a `text()` that when atmomised to a string is equal to `name`. From there you then select the 1st preceding `h1`.

So for example, given the XML input:

```
<div>
  <h1>title1</h1>
  <p>stuff</p>
  <h1>title2</h1>
  <p>more stuff</p>
  <h2>name</h2>
  <p>other stuff</p>
</div>
```

You would get the following XML output as a result of your XPath expression:

```
<h1>title2</h1>
```

Hope that helps you understand...

Comment: Thanks a lot! Really helpfull. Generaly i couldn't figure out what is going on with this brackets in first expression... ;]  One last question if i can.. Is the expression: '//table[not(head)]' return all table elements without thead tag?

Comment: Your expression `//table[not(head)]` will return all table elements that do not have a child element called `head`. I am not sure if where you typed `thead` it was just a typo and you meant `head`, if not then just change `head` to `thead` in the above. Also if `head` is not an immediate child of `table`, you could use `//table[not(.//head)]` to find all `table` elements that have no descendant elements called `head`.

Comment: Yes yes, i mean `thead`, little mistake. Thanks a lot for your help :)